# How to commit only file renames, not actual content changes in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, rename

I renamed a several files in the repo, and made some changes in them. Now, I would like only to commit the fact that I renamed the files, and then separately commit the changes. Is that possible in Mercurial?

One option I see is to shelve all my changes, and then manually record all renames. I'm wondering is there a more automated, less error-prone, way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this with Mercurial — commit will always record both the rename and the new file content.

However, you can do it with a couple of steps. If the working copy parent is X, then do:

1. Commit the mixed renames and changes, call this Y
2. Extract the renames and commit those onto X, call this commit Z
3. Rebase Y (the mixed commit) onto Z (the renames only). Rebase is smart enough to see that the renames in Y are already in Z

On the command line it looks like this:

```
$ hg commit -m "mixed commit with both changes and renames"
$ hg update -r "p1(.)"
$ hg diff -c tip | grep "^\(diff\|rename\)" | hg import -m 'renames' -
$ hg rebase -s -2 -d .
```

Comment: This did the trick. The first commit message will seem strange, as the commit will contain only changes :) Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you should probably use a better commit message than the one I proposed above :)